# How to maintain two different version in single android app

Tags: android

I developed one application, Now I want to make my app free version and paid version. Free version contains few features, paid version contains all features. so How to maintain two versions with same code? Can any one help me.

Comment: You can define two roles in the app and identify them by a unique "code". 
The current user/app status can be stored in say SharedPreferences.
The left panel/options menu can be populated based on the value stored in the apps SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 2):

Build flavors are a very good solution for this. See https://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html for more information.

What I find very usefull is that you can replace specific files / values for your flavor and keep the rest the same. We've used it to build two different applications from the same code, only defering in layout and package names.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I developed app in eclipse, how to maintain this in eclipse?

Comment: What do you use to build your application, Eclipse itself? Don't know solution for that. Would advice to switch to Gradle as build tool (can also be executed from Eclipse), because that's the standard Google maintains.